# sql query to select most recent record along with the empty records

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having 2 tables..i am moving status history to one table and display it in another table..the second table fetches recent status and show it in the web page [image: output]

like this i need..but i am getting as

[image: needed output]

I need the updated records along with the empty status record. My query is:

```
with ctr as
(
 select en.status update,ed.no,row_number()
 over (partition by ed.no order by en.update descending) as [RN], 
 ed.[conference date],ed.conference name,ed.region,ed.inquiry,
 ed.attended by,ed.doctor name,ed.hospital,ed.contact no,ed.email, ed.adds,
 CONVERT(VAR CHAR(10),en.[update], 103) as update,ed.closed,
 CONVERT(VAR CHAR(10),ed.[closing date],103) as closing date,
 ed.closed by, ed.revenue, ed.approve status, ed.Enid from inquiries_details ed
 inner join
 inquiries en on ed.Enid = en.Enid
 inner join
 staff_details SD on ed.region = SD.state
 where region = 'Maharashtra' 
)
 select * from ctr where RN = 1
```

can anyone help me

Comment: Add more details. what you have mentioned is not enough and not clear too.

Comment: if i am having 3 records and i updated the status for 2 records..i am getting those two updated records from the date of update..but i also need to list that remaining one record which is not updated

Comment: I don't really understand your question here. But I'm guessing your problem is "Why am I not getting No 10 record in the first table?". Do some debugging first. Remove all the where clauses and see. Next joins.I can see you are using inner joins. Try changing them to outer joins and see.

Comment: ya ur guess is right..i just use left join and i got the result what i need..thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can your tried with below query, might be issue of inner join.. change it to left joins

```
with ctr as
(
 select en.status update,ed.no,row_number()
 over (partition by ed.no order by en.update descending) as [RN], 
 ed.[conference date],ed.conference name,ed.region,ed.inquiry,
 ed.attended by,ed.doctor name,ed.hospital,ed.contact no,ed.email, ed.adds,
 CONVERT(VAR CHAR(10),en.[update], 103) as update,ed.closed,
 CONVERT(VAR CHAR(10),ed.[closing date],103) as closing date,
 ed.closed by, ed.revenue, ed.approve status, ed.Enid from inquiries_details ed
 left join
 inquiries en on ed.Enid = en.Enid
 left join
 staff_details SD on ed.region = SD.state
 where region = 'Maharashtra' 
)
 select * from ctr where RN = 1
```